# Multiple column group by in slick with mapped projections

Tags: scala, group-by, slick

I have defined a query below containing 7 tables.No of columns to be selected from few table exceed limit of 22, so defined projections as below. The query also need to have a group by on certain columns, but I am unable to figure out how to apply the mapped projection in group by function.

```
    implicit s =>
    val query = for
    {
      (t1, t2) <- Table1 leftJoin Table2 on
        (_.t1A === _.t2A)
      (t3, t4) <- Table3 leftJoin Table4 on (_.t3A === _.t4A)
      t5 <- Table5 if t1.t1B === t5.t5B
      t6 <- Table6 if t6.t6C === t4.t4C && t6.t6D === t5.t5D
      rit <- Table7 if t7.t7E === t1.t1E          

    } yield (t1.t1A ~ t1.t1B ~ t1.t1C ~ t1.t1D ~
        t1.t1E ~ t1.t1F ~ t1.t1G ~ t1.t1H ~
        t1.t1I.? ~ t1.t1J ~ t1.t1K ~ t1.t1L ~
        t1.t1M ~ t1.t1N <>(Table1Rec1.apply _, Table1Rec1.unapply _),

        t1.t1O ~ t1.t1P ~ t1.t1Q ~ t1.t1R ~
          t1.t1S ~ t1.t1T ~ t1.t1U ~ t1.t1V ~
          t1.t1W ~ t1.t1X ~ t1.t1Y ~ t1.t1Z <>(Table1Rec2.apply _,
          Table1Rec2.unapply _),

        t1.t1AA ~
          t1.t1AB ~ t1.t1AC ~ t1.t1AD ~ t1.t1AE ~
          t1.t1AF ~ t1.t1AG.? ~ t1.t1AH ~ t1.t1AI.? <>(Table1Rec3
          .apply _, Table1Rec3.unapply _),

       t2.t2A ~ t2.t2B ~ t2.t2C ~ t2.t2D ~ t2.t2E ~ t2.t2F ~ t2
          .t2G <>(Table2Rec1.apply _, Table2Rec1.unapply _),

        t3.t3A ~ t3.t3B ~ t3.t3C ~ t3.t3D <>(Table3Rec1.apply _, Table3Rec1.unapply _),

        t4.t4A.? ~ t4.t4B ~ t4.t4C <>(Table4Rec1.apply _, Table4Rec1.unapply _),

        t5.t5A ~ t5.t5B <>(Table5Rec1.apply _,
          Table5Rec1.unapply _),

        t6.t6A ~ t6.t6B <>(Table6Rec1.apply _, Table6Rec1.unapply _),

        t7.t7A ~ t7.t7B <>(Table7Rec1.apply _, Table7Rec1.unapply _)

        )

     val query2 = query.groupBy(????).map
      {
        ????

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
query.groupBy(_._1._1 /*t1A*/).map{ case (key,groups) => groups.map(_._2._2/*t1P*/).sum }
```

?

Be aware that there are some known bugs in groupBy in Slick 1.0.1. Also if you get an exception like "Read NULL value" the reason is, that Slick is currently not capable to automatically handle the type change that comes with an outer join. An outer join makes a type that is usually not nullable suddenly nullable and if a null is actually found Slick throws a surprised exception. This will be fixed in a future version of Slick. For now you have to explicity call `.?` on non-nullable columns which could have become null. As a consequence your mappers will not work properly either, because they will read the columns as non-nullable. The workaround pattern is implemented here for example: https://github.com/freekh/play-slick/blob/f7256162b88b9e914dfce3eb1a5955005414ae4d/samples/computer-database/app/models/Models.scala#L113 But it will be tedious with such a large number of columns. Consider code-generation.

Related answers
[Slick left/right/outer joins with Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386593/slick-left-right-outer-joins-with-option/20387749#20387749)
[Slick left outer join fetching whole joined row as option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990365/slick-left-outer-join-fetching-whole-joined-row-as-option/19063345#19063345)

The topic is also mentioned in my Scala eXchange 2013 talk, where I show how you can ease the situation with code-generation in Slick 2.0 until the proper type support in Slick becomes available.

Comment: query.groupBy(_._1._1 /*t1A*/) does not work, since _._1. only gives access to mapped projection not actual field. I was hoping I could use "f" to get access to column from projection but did not understand correctly the parameter it expecting. Meanwhile looking at other options you have listed.

Comment: Not sure what f is. My best suggestion: leave out the mapped projections and work with only the columns you actually need where you run the query.