# Slick: Read nullable values as option when left join

Tags: sql, scala, nullable, slick-2.0

Problem when using Slick to join: I have 2 tables User and UserInfo and I want to leftJoin them to get user's info. I've tried this:

```
val q = for{
  (user,info) <- User leftJoin UserInfo on (_.id === _.userid)
} yield(user, info)
```

But the UserInfo table has some nullable field, so when I try to execute the query:

```
q.map(user_info => (user_info._1,user_info._2)).list
```

It makes error because user_info._2 has some null values. I know a solution that yield each field in UserInfo and add getOrElse(None) for nullable fields. However, UserInfo has many field so I don't want to use this.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If the nullable fields are defined as `Option`s in the schema they will be returned so, I suspect your problem is elsewhere, for example what kind of exception are you getting exactly? How is your schema defined?

Comment: `x.getOrElse(None)` should be exactly the same as `x`, right? How could that solve your problem?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20386593/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/14990365

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you CAN do, is this define a function that does the conversion, and then use it in your map:

```
def nullToOption[A](input: A): Option[A] = input match {
  case null => None
  case x    => Some(x)
}
```

And then you just use it in your map.

I made a simple example using a simple list:

```
val lst = List("Hello", null, "hi", null)

val newlst = map lst nullToOption
```

`newList` is now the following: `List(Some("Hello"), None, Some("hi"), None)`

Of course you can modify nullToOption to fit your needs; here's a version that takes tuples:

```
def nullToOption[A, B](input: (A,B)): (Option[A], Option[B]) = input match {
  case (x, y)       => (Some(x), Some(y))
  case (x, null)    => (Some(x), None)
  case (null, y)    => (None, Some(y))
  case (null, null) => (None, None)
}
```

Comment: Your `nullToOption` for a non-tuple argument already exists in the standard library as `Option.apply` (`Option(...)`).

Comment: I didn't know that, I just wrote this off the top of my head